# Mudar cursor do mouse usando WINAPI

Tags: windows, winapi

Não consigo mudar o cursor do mouse, quando solto o botão direito do mesmo. Parte de meu 
código:

```
 case WM_RBUTTONUP :
            SetCursor( LoadCursor( hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDC_MEUCURSOR1)));  
            ShowCursor(TRUE);
       return 0;
```

O cursor simplesmente some, não aparece nada. Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Em algum lugar do seu programa você faz `ShowCursor(FALSE);`?

Comment: Cara não sei mais talvez esse vídeo te ajude!
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0aJPBu-1YKY

Answer (score 1):

Verifique a função LoadCursor, é muito comum o erro estar no recurso IDC_MEUCURSOR1 (valor do resource.h é um, valor real do recurso é outro)